# How to get title from html file using directory - php

Tags: php, function, title, page-title

Fairly new to php, so bear with me. I'm trying to figure out how to read a directory/folder and return both the filename/path and the title of that file into a li.

```
$handle = opendir('.'); 
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){ 
  $extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1)); 
  if($extension == 'html' || $extension == 'htm' || $extension == 'php'){ 
      echo "<a href='".$filename."'><li class='"iso_block"'><span>"**Title Tag Here**"</span></li></a>";
  } 
}
```

^code from miro(cheers/thanks)

js.Fiddle link for visual: http://jsfiddle.net/AagGZ/547/

Comment: have you tried [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)?

Comment: load the file in the dom and search for a title tag (slow) or preg_match("#<title>(.*)</title>#",...) it.

Comment: jsFiddle for testing php ? what are you trying to achieve man ?

Comment: jsFiddle is just a test bench for visuals (To let illustrate what I want visually without any functions).

whats the benefit of using glob vs dir?

Comment: You'll need to use something like `DOMDocument` and parse the HTML, and then just target the title tag and get the content, shouldn't be to hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$handle = opendir('.');
$dom    = new DOMDocument();

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){ 
    $extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file, '.'), 1));
    if ($extension == 'html' || $extension == 'htm' || $extension == 'php') {
        $title = 'Untitled Document';

        if($dom->loadHTMLFile($urlpage)) {
            $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");
            if ($list->length > 0) {
                $title = $list->item(0)->textContent;
            }
        }

        echo "<a href='$filename'><li class='iso_block'><span>$title</span></li></a>";
    } 
}
```